# How to align image with text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

The code below is from a simple SwiftUI ContentView. It displays an image and text, but the image stretches taking the starting position.

```
struct CustomView: View {
var imageName: String = ""
var text: String = ""
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 05){
        Image(imageName).resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
        Text(text).font(.system(size: 10, weight: .light, design: .default))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width:60)
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what this is asking. The code you've shared doesn't seem to match the image you've shown and I'm not clear on how what you are experiencing is different than your desired result.

Comment: It's like if I call three times CustomView with different imageName and text, the view should appear like above

Comment: And what about what you're experiencing is different? That the text isn't left-aligned?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: images on the left-hand side stretched as per the width of the first one(150+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the "...image stretches taking the starting position".
However, here is a basic test with your code adding ".fixedSize()".
What exactly do you think is not correct with the results?

```
struct CustomView: View {
    @State var imageName: String = ""  // <---
    @State var text: String = ""      // <---
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 05){
            Image(systemName: imageName).resizable()
                .scaledToFit() // <--- 
                .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
            Text(text).font(.system(size: 10, weight: .light, design: .default))
                .frame(width:60)
        }.fixedSize()       // <----
        .border(Color.red)  // for testing
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomView(imageName:"clock", text:"clock")
            CustomView(imageName:"info", text:"info")
            CustomView(imageName:"globe", text:"globe")
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what if the image size is not the same. The first image (150+) is 50*30 and the others are 20*20. That's where all the small image stretches

Comment: you could try:             Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 30)   or use .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)

Comment: Thanks a lot, .scaledToFit() worked befor placing to frame